# How to get number of items that has been shipped in a Magento order?

Tags: php, magento, model-view-controller

I wanna get the number of items that has been shipped in a Magento order. For example, a person orders 10 items. 4 has been shipped. I wanna get the number 4 in this case, then combine with the rest of 6 items which is on a second shipping batch. Check if 4 + 6 equals total number of items 10, if the second shipping batch shipped out all 6, change the order status to Complete. If not, change to Partial Shipment.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

```
$order = Mage::getModel('sales/order')->load($orderId);
$total_ordered_items = $order->getData('total_qty_ordered');
$num_of_shipped_items = 0;

foreach ($order->getAllVisibleItems() as $item){
   //$item->getQtyOrdered() // Number of item ordered
   $num_of_shipped_items += $item->getQtyShipped();  
   //$item->getQtyInvoiced()
}

if($num_of_shipped_items == $total_ordered_items){
    // set status to complete
}
else{
    // Partial 
}
```